# PHP7+ Sorting and Array based on Array Instance Value(s)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, stdclass

**Question:**

What is the best **PHP 7+** approach for sorting the following `array` based on the array instance (`string`) value of `array->status`.

**Goal:**

Re-order the `array` based on the `status` value. If the value is "`StatusAvailable`", I would want to move the `array` instance to the top of the `array`. Since the `array` *may* contain multiple instances where a status of "`StatusAvailable`" is defined, the next ordering condition fallback would be the `date` value.

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
       (
           [date]   => 1432875600000
           [value1] => TEXT
           [value2] => TEXT
           [value3] => TEXT
           [value4] => TEXT
           [value5] => TEXT
           [status] => 
           [value6] => TEXT
           [value7] =>
       )

    [1] => stdClass Object
       (
           [date]   => 1432875600000
           [value1] => TEXT
           [value2] => TEXT
           [value3] => TEXT
           [value4] => TEXT
           [value5] => TEXT
           [status] => StatusAvailable
           [value6] => TEXT
           [value7] =>
       )


    [2] => stdClass Object
       (
           [date]   => 14472543800000
           [value1] => TEXT
           [value2] => TEXT
           [value3] => TEXT
           [value4] => TEXT
           [value5] => TEXT
           [status] => SomeOtherStatus
           [value6] => TEXT
           [value7] =>
       )

    [3] => stdClass Object
       (
           [date]   => 1467349200000
           [value1] => TEXT
           [value2] => TEXT
           [value3] => TEXT
           [value4] => TEXT
           [value5] => TEXT
           [status] => StatusAvailable
           [value6] => NO
           [value7] =>
       )

    # the array list can/will continue at random length
)
```

Comment: [usort](http://php.net/usort).

Comment: How do you sort when it's not StatusAvailable? which comes first  SomeOtherStatus or NoStatus? Why don't you turn your status parameter into a map having `['label'=> StatusAvailable,'sortOrder'=>1]` then you can easily use usort on sortOrder

Comment: The array is delivered from an API, pre-formatted. The exercise would be to re-order what we received based on the "status" of each instance, then, it multiple are returned, the next sorting should fall back on the "date". Hope that makes sense! @HiradRoshandel

Comment: @JonStirling, the goal of this post was to archive demonstrations of recommendations based on opinion or performance. I'm aware of `usort`, however, I would prefer to have demonstrations aligned with modern standards presented. Thanks for providing the reference link however!

Comment: @Joey Then I'm afraid you might have the wrong idea about SO. For example, asking for things as a matter of opinion is explicitly off-topic. Might be worth read the help section :).

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton I was referring directly to OPs comment to me, which stated `the goal of this post was to archive demonstrations of recommendations based on opinion ......`